# how to create jira custom field using postman

Tags: postman, jira

i have to create jira custom field like
Maturity State,Responsible,Collaborative Space can u please help with json

```
{
    "fields": {  
        "project": {
            "key": "MP"
        },
        "description": "Don't forget to do this too.",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Epic"
        },    
        "summary": "You must specify a summary of the issue.",
        "customfield_10104":[{
            "value" :{{This is akshay}}
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]. You need to add more details to clarify what your issue is.